# Fluid jQuery page transition

Tags: jquery, html, optimization, transition

So here is my problem: I am designing a website that is using jQuery to transition the main frame of a webpage. The index page has a banner with a 450 height that reduces to 200px when going to the other pages. There is a button on the main page (about a page down) that is supposed to SCROLL back to the top of the page, and THEN do the page transitio. The problem here is that whenever I click the button, it does the page transition WHILE it is scrolling up , thus making it look like a sloppy transition.

Here is my function call:

```
$('a[href=#services]').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow').delay(1500).animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
    $.indexClear();
    $.serviceSET();
    $.servicelinkSET();
    return false;
});
```

The functions calls are all composed of hide() and fadeIn() and nothing else. Any idea? Also, the delay function does not seem to be working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your scroll left/right code anywhere, but it sounds like you need to do this in a callback. Once the animate to top of page finishes, run the left/right code.

```
$('element').animate({scrollTop: 0}, function() {
    //callback is called when first animation finishes
    $('element2').animate({left: 100});
});
```

Comment: thanks, this helped it out. my only other question is now when I run a jQuery script (say an animation #1), and then i click another button that causes an event for animation #2, and BOTH use the same div, how can I have the second animation overwrite the action of the first one? I am getting a result of the second animation NOT being run. Is there a queue I can create?